Reading Eumetsat METOP native file format .nat with python
I downloaded testwise a file from the Eumetsat Data Service (IASI_SND_02_M01_20240519062358Z_20240519080557Z_N_O_20240519072825Z.nat). However, the file is in their native format .nat. I gave it a try and tried to open it with the python library xarray:
import xarray as xr
df = xr.open_dataset('path/to/file.nat')

However, this was not successful, it seems it is not able to the read the datafile.
Does someone have experience on how to read the datafile .nat from Eumetsat with python?
UPDATE
I found a tutorial from Darius Görgen (https://www.dariusgoergen.com/contents/blog/2020-06-14-nat2tif/index.html) which shows how to read .nat data with the library satpy.
I installed the libraries and I tried to the read the data with the satpy-reader 'seviri_l1b_native' as it says, that it can read .nat-files (native fileformat from eumetsat).
I have put the file into the directory of the jupyter notebook and run to the following commands:
file = "IASI_SND_02_M01_20240519062358Z_20240519080557Z_N_O_20240519072825Z.nat"

scn = Scene(reader='seviri_l1b_hrit', filenames=[file])

However, it seems that the fileformat also differs between satellites. The example from Darious Görgen uses Meteosat-data, but the data I have here is from the Metop-satellite, and I wasn't able to read the data, but I'm getting warnings and in the end an error
WARNING:satpy.readers.yaml_reader:No filenames found for reader: seviri_l1b_hrit   

WARNING:satpy.readers:Don't know how to open the following files: {'IASI_SND_02_M01_20240519062358Z_20240519080557Z_N_O_20240519072825Z.nat'}

ValueError: No supported files found


So I guess I cannot read Metop data with the satpy library or I'm doing something not in the way as it is supposed to be.
Maybe somebody knows how to read specifically the .nat-data from the Metop satellite? I adjusted my question accordingly.

Have you tried to follow this tutorial https://www.dariusgoergen.com/contents/blog/2020-06-14-nat2tif/index.html?

Hi, yes, I found it too, and am actually busy with installing the libraries. Thank you!

I wanted to ask if you were able to find a solution to your problem. I’m currently facing the same issue, and I noticed there haven’t been any updates here. I’d really appreciate it if you could share any insights or solutions you found for reading EUMETSAT METOP native file format (.nat) with Python.

@AnkitaPatel Patel It is a while ago, that I had a look into it. If I remember correctly, I wasn't able to read the .nat-data, but found an alternative. However, I don't remeber it ad hoc, but I will have a look into it this week and will let you know.
